# How to make an alert when a form item is not answered?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to JS. But basically, I'm creating a form. Using JavaScript, how do I take a form so that you *must* fill in form data?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<form>
            <p>First Name:</p>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form">
            <p>Last Name:</p>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form">
            <p>Email:</p>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form">
            <p>Questions / Concerns:</p>
            <textarea name="concerns" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to make an alert pop up if someone presses the "Submit" button while a field is empty?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use document.getElementByTagName to get the input tag
Use addEventListner with first parameter as blur to detect input leave 
Use this.value within if statement to check if empty
Alert something

```
var element=document.getElementByTagName(input);
element.addEventListner("blur",myFunction);
function myFunction(){
if(this.value==''){
alert ("write something");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways of solving this particular problem.

The easiest way would be to use the required tag in elements:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form" required>
```

Edit: This may not work in very old browsers.But I don't believe you need to worry about that now.

Use required tag in all of your input elements which you need filling compulsorily.

Once you have your basic problem solved, look at using javascript functions for validation. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Once you know this, you can safely progress to reading on how validation is done on large projects- https://validatejs.org/